# One to many lookup, converted to a one to one dimension

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am struggling figuring out how to transform a one to many table structure from a transact database into a one to one dimension for a data warehouse.

In the transaction database the data structure is as:

**Root Record** (Parent_ID)

**Lookup Table** "Many Parent_IDs" (Patent_ID, Child_ID)

**Reference Table** (Child_ID, Name)

Joining to my reference table brings back a data set that looks like such:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ Root_ID     ║ Root_Code ║ Child_ID ║ Child_Name ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║           1 ║ 1000      ║       22 ║  Name 1    ║
║           1 ║ 1000      ║       23 ║  Name 2    ║
║           1 ║ 1000      ║       24 ║  Name 3    ║
║           1 ║ 1000      ║       25 ║  Name 4    ║
║           2 ║ 1150      ║       67 ║  Name 5    ║
║           2 ║ 1150      ║       68 ║  Name 6    ║
║           2 ║ 1150      ║       69 ║  Name 7    ║
║           3 ║ 2019      ║       11 ║  Name 8    ║
║           3 ║ 2019      ║       12 ║  Name 9    ║
║           5 ║ 2010      ║       91 ║  Name 10   ║
║           5 ║ 2010      ║       92 ║  Name 11   ║
║           5 ║ 2010      ║       93 ║  Name 12   ║
║           5 ║ 2010      ║       94 ║  Name 13   ║
║           5 ║ 2010      ║       95 ║  Name 14   ║
║           5 ║ 2010      ║       96 ║  Name 15   ║
║           6 ║ 5010      ║       33 ║  Name 16   ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

What I am after in my dimension is to know, Root_ID (1) has the values of Child_ID(22,23,24,25) and be able to reference that using the generated key on the dimension.

> Keep in mind I can never predict how many child records there will be,
>   so creating X about of columns in my dimension isn't an option.

I am sure a wise data warehouse mind than me knows how this is normally handled.

To illustrate the desired result:

Fact Record (Dimension_Root_Key = 1)

Dimension (Key 1, Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, Name 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I should have studied a little more. I have learnt the nomenclature of "Bridging" tables.

Knowing that the kimball group has some great demos on how to achieve what I wanted to. For further reading on [Bridging tables](https://www.kimballgroup.com/2014/05/design-tip-166-potential-bridge-table-detours/)